# How to grep only the recently matched search string?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, email, grep

I have a log file which gets updated every second. I am `grep`'ing some string and pulls that search result to a temp file. 
Then I am sending that temp file result to my email. 
I am running this script in `cron`.
But when the cron triggers the script again and when the script catches the newly searched string, it gives me the previous/old result also in the temp file.

*For example my log file looks like below but not exactly:*

```
2018-02-15 14:36:47,344 INFO : Bread butter jam

2018-02-15 14:37:22,566 INFO : trees

2018-02-15 14:37:22,636 INFO : fruits

2018-02-15 14:37:22,636 INFO : veggies

2018-02-15 14:37:22,745 INFO : junkies

2018-02-15 14:37:23,648 INFO : Bread butter jam

2018-02-15 14:37:23,659 INFO : cakes

2018-02-15 14:37:23,734 INFO : cookies

2018-02-15 14:37:23,767 INFO : meat

2018-02-15 14:37:23,874 INFO : yogurt
```

I want **Bread butter jam** to be stored in a temp file each time when it comes in the log file.

**How to pull only the newly searched result to the temp file?**

Sorry for my bad English and I am new to bash.

Comment: Posting sample Input_file will help us to help you, please post it with CODE TAGS here.

Comment: Store line count of log file in some file and use `tail` to get lines from that line count + 1

Comment: @v8sagar I have edited my question.

Comment: Remember when you ran the script the previous time and only search the log for entries after that point in time. See [extract data from log file in specified range of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575267/extract-data-from-log-file-in-specified-range-of-time) for details.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: Let `grep` number the lines for you, and let `tail` take only the last one. You can then immediately see if the new is different from the old because the line number will be different `grep -n "Bread" YourFile | tail -n 1`

Comment: @MarkSetchell What if there are 3 occurences of "Bread" between the 2 logs ? You'd only get the last one

Comment: @Aserre I take your point - though I am not actually sure what the OP wants, so I just made a comment instead of an answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned in the comments, you should compare the current log size with the length of the previous one you would have stored in a file.

Something like that should do the trick :

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_LINECOUNT=$(cat /path/to/LogFile | wc - l)
#redirection is here in case the old_count file doesn't exist
OLD_LINECOUNT=$(cat /path/to/old_count 2>/dev/null)

tail -n $((CURRENT_LINECOUNT - ${OLD_LINECOUNT:-0})) /path/to/LogFile | grep "Bread butter jam" > /path/to/temp/file
echo $CURRENT_LINECOUNT > /path/to/old_count

#here, your logic to send the temp file
```

Answer (score 1):

When the logfile is small enough for grepping strings each minute, you can use the fact that new lines will have a different timestamp.
Something like

```
mytmp=/tmp/breakfast.tmp
mylasttmp=/tmp/breakfast.lasttmp
myattachment=/tmp/breakfast.now
test -f ${mytmp} && { echo "Last cron processing still running"; exit 1;}
touch ${mytmp}

grep -E "Bread butter jam" logfile > ${mytmp}

comm -3 ${mytmp} ${mylasttmp} > ${myattachment}
# process ${myattachment} and when that is finished...
mv ${myattachment} ${mylasttmp}
rm ${mytmp}
```