# How to grep the file with time range

Tags: bash, grep

I have log file, need to grep the file with line having `Connection Refused` between 10 and 11

File

```
2018-07-11 10:12:06,288 - Admin logged in
2018-07-11 10:15:06,288 - User logged in Connection Refused
2018-07-11 10:16:06,288 - Admin logged in
2018-07-11 10:18:06,288 - User logged in Connection Refused
2018-07-11 11:19:06,288 - User logged in Connection Refused
```

Desired Out

```
2018-07-11 10:15:06,288 - User logged in Connection Refused
2018-07-11 10:18:06,288 - User logged in Connection Refused
```

Command

```
grep - i "Connection Refused" file
```

Comment: post your command

Comment: `grep - i "Connection Refused" file || grep '2018-07-11 10'`

Comment: code should be in the body of your Q, not as a comment (please). Try changing `||` to just one `|`. (`||` is logical OR for the shell). Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract data from log file in specified range of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575267/extract-data-from-log-file-in-specified-range-of-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '$0>="2018-07-11 10" && $0<="2018-07-11 11" && /Connection Refused/' file
```

Output:

```
2018-07-11 10:15:06,288 - User logged in Connection Refused
2018-07-11 10:18:06,288 - User logged in Connection Refused
```

Answer (score 2):

use below comman

```
grep  -i "Connection Refused" file | grep "2018-07-11 10"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep  -i "Connection Refused" yourlogfile | grep "2018-07-11 10"
```